# Using Packer to install Debian

Tags: debian, packer

I'm new to both Packer and Debian. I'm currently attempting to install Debian using Packer, but I've encountered a challenge:
As you can see in the image, the preseed.cfg file isn't being retrieved during the installation process.
Is there something I'm overlooking?
Below is the Packer code I'm using:

```
packer {
  required_plugins {
    vsphere = {
      version = "= v1.2.4"
      source  = "github.com/hashicorp/vsphere"
    }
    ansible = {
      version = "~> 1"
      source = "github.com/hashicorp/ansible"
    }
    inspec = {
      version = ">= 0.0.1"
      source  = "github.com/hashicorp/inspec"
    }
  }
}

source "vsphere-iso" "srv-lin-debian-base" {
  vcenter_server          = var.vcenter_server
  username                = var.vsphere_username
  password                = var.vsphere_password
  insecure_connection     = true

  vm_name                 = "${var.vm_name}-debian-base"
  cluster                 = var.vsphere_cluster
  resource_pool           = var.vsphere_resource_pool
  datastore               = var.vsphere_datastore
  folder                  = var.vsphere_folder

  vm_version              = var.vm_hw_version
  guest_os_type           = "otherGuest"

  boot_command            = [
     "<esc><wait>",
     "install <wait>",
     "file=/preseed/preseed.cfg <wait>",
     "debian-installer=en_US <wait>",
     "auto <wait>",
     "locale=en_US <wait>",
     "kbd-chooser/method=us <wait>",
     "fb=false <wait>",
     "debconf/frontend=noninteractive <wait>",
     "console-setup/ask_detect=false <wait>",
     "console-keymaps-at/keymap=us <wait>",
     "keyboard-configuration/xkb-keymap=us <wait>",
     "<enter><wait>"
  ]
  boot_wait               = "15s"

  communicator            = "ssh"
  ssh_username            = var.ssh_username
  ssh_password            = var.ssh_password
  ssh_handshake_attempts  = "100"
  ssh_timeout             = "15m"

  CPUs                    = var.vm_numcpu
  RAM                     = var.vm_memory
  RAM_reserve_all         = true

  network_adapters {
    network               = "DPortGroup-Public"
    network_card          = "vmxnet3"
  }
  storage {
    disk_controller_index = 0
    disk_size             = 102400
    disk_thin_provisioned = true
  }
  disk_controller_type    = ["pvscsi"]
  
  
  iso_url                 = local.iso_authenticatedurl
  iso_checksum            = var.iso_checksum

  export {
    force                 = false
    output_directory      = "/tmp/vm-export"
  }
}

build {
  sources = [
    "source.vsphere-iso.srv-lin-debian-base"
    ]

  provisioner "shell-local" {
    pause_before     = "0m30s"
    inline = [
      "yamllint --version",
      "packer --version",
      "ansible --version",
      "inspec --version",
      "ovftool --version"
    ]
  }
  provisioner "shell" {
    inline = ["echo 'Completed template build'"]
  }
}
```

**Error:**
[image]

I didn't find any clear reference in the Packer documentation and going through Debian, they explain the following:

https://www.debian.org/releases/buster/amd64/apbs02.en.html

```
if you're booting a remastered CD:
  preseed/file=/cdrom/preseed.cfg
  preseed/file/checksum=5da499872becccfeda2c4872f9171c3d
```

Note that preseed/url can be shortened to just url, preseed/file to just file, and preseed/file/checksum to just preseed-md5 when they are passed as boot parameters.

Could you please help me with that issue?
I really appreciate your time

Comment: Have you checked the boxcutter repo examples for Debian? They are usually helpful for `vsphere` builders.

Comment: checked but I didnt find anything

Comment: Looking some examples, I see  this" url=http://{{.HTTPIP}}:{{.HTTPPort}}/preseed.cfg " but still getting same error. Actually, I didn't get this syntax.